# Replacing a Core Data property by a new one avoiding Zombie objects

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsset

I have two NSManagedObject named Event and Image. The Event class has a property (relationship with a inverse relationship also) named images, which is composed of a NSSet containing objects of the class Image.

When updating the Events from the server I want just to replace the old Image NSSet by a new one, which also could contain previously existing Image objects or new ones. What I do then is something like:

```
event.images = [NSSet setWithArray:imagesParser_.imagesArray];
```

This fulfills my purpose, but my worry is that still some Image objects belonging to the old NSSet, now without any link to any Event, could remain forever in the database. I thought that maybe doing a clean (looking in the DB for Image objects without Event and removing them from DB) after the update would fix this, but I do not know how efficient it is.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you make the relationship required in the core data editor, you can make sure that trying to create orphaned entities will result in an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting objects with coredata is pretty quick. I would personally go through and delete all of the objects attached to my event and then add the new ones.

You could also take your approach and infrequently go through and remove all images without any events. This only becomes problematic if, in the future, images can exist without an event (say you create a new type of data that wants photos). It really is not time or memory intensive.

It is a good idea to keep your database clean, otherwise you could run into complications in the future. Any effort you put into it now generally benefits you in the future. If you do not need an object anymore delete it somehow.

Comment: Thanks Firo. The only problem I see to delete all the objects and then add the new ones is that some old images could still be part of the new NSSet. Wouldn't be deleting an Image and then creating it with the same Id a loss of time?

Comment: you can associate a predicate with the fetch request which would fetch only those images objects whose event relationship is nil.

Comment: Well technically in the solution you provided you are not reusing any of the images (unless _imagesArray handles that manually) since coredata doesn't use properties (or at least the properties you give it) when comparing entities. So compared to your solution, no, you probably wouldn't notice any difference. There are ways you could attempt to change this and make it more effective but it would require some extra implementation.